# Making a super-kosher meal for my dad

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

I'm making my father his favorite meal, and he's - I mean, I'm - [super-religious](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WfFyBqN8kW8), so it has to be super-kosher.

I want to make sure that every aspect is as kosher as you can get it, and I think I've got it all down except for one aspect.

To make the meal, I'm going to shoot a really nice deer with my trusty Winchester. Of course, since the bullets will be entering the body of the animal, I'm making them myself from scratch to ensure that they adhere to all of the kosher rules. Naturally, I'm not using any iron, [since that could remind you of swords](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9881#v=22&showrashi=true), and thus of death, which isn't nice.

For the [gunpowder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gunpowder), I'm making sure that the charcoal comes from wood from trees that are beyond suspicion of [*orlah*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orlah), and I'm sourcing the [brimstone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfur) carefully from certified non-[Sodom](http://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.19.24?lang=bi) sources. Finally, the [saltpeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niter), of course, can't come from bat guano, since bats aren't kosher, so I have to use the mineral kind, which comes from the ground.

But if saltpeter comes from the ground, then I need to make sure it's [tithed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_tithe) properly before I use it in a kosher meal, right? [I'm not sure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demai) if the miner I'm getting it from tithed it or not, so I need to do it myself to be safe. The problem is that I'm not sure what procedure I'm supposed to use, and what formula to recite, when tithing the saltpeter. Can you help?

**How do you tithe from saltpeter?**

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: I listened to that song (and its prequel, the aveirah song) and now it's going to be in my head for weeks.

Comment: @Daniel Shhhh... Ixnay on the eirahvay! I was never into any of that stuff and I'm not anymore and it's none of your business and my father might see this!

Comment: Doesn't shooting the deer make it automatically non-kosher?

Answer (score 3):

you should ask Eisav for the best advice regarding both tithing salt and hunting

Comment: I had the same thought, but others could probably benefit from a reference. +1

Comment: I think that was OP's point.

Comment: Thanks, Dude! You should ask Dude for the best advice regarding latte smileys.

Comment: While this link might contain the answer, it's better to quote the relevant parts here.  What does Eisav say?

Comment: @MonicaCellio Here's ["What does Haman say?"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b74IcmDxGtY), in case it's helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Since it is Peter's salt, you should first make sure that you have purchased it honestly. Since it was originally peterssalt and is now saltpeter, then it has already been tithed.

An alternate meaning might be that it is a statue of Peter made from salt so that you are getting a mitzvah by destroying an icon of Avodas Zara. As such it does not need to be tithed.

Next load your gun with a harpoon and not a bullet. Shoot the harpoon so as to shecht the deer so that it is not neveilah.

However, make sure that you get home before your brother has served the korbon Pesach to your father. Once he has done that, your father will be unable to eat your deer and the work will have been wasted. Besides, once he sees what your brother has done, he will realize what you have been up to.

Answer (score 1):

To take the tithe from "saltpeter?" just take off one tenth of the letters. As to which one, I recommend the question mark so you are left with "saltpeter". If you take off the S, you would get "altpeter?" which might be a political reference.

Comment: Huh??? "To take the tithe from "saltpeter?"  The word "saltpeter" has 9 letters!. What does 9/10 of a letter mean?